# Soundcloud Player locking up on Mobile / iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, soundcloud

I'm embedding multiple SoundCloud players on this site: http://www.familyartists.com

Hitting the Play button on the SoundCloud player makes the play button fade to a pause button, but doesn't actually play and the site freezes up for a while.

Is the page hogging up too many recourses for it to play?

Comment: What mobile browser are you testing on?  Safari?  Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

On an iPhone 5 running 8.1 using Safari I can play one track after another, but the UI will periodically freeze and tracks do not always start when the play button is pressed.  Checking Safari logs, I see a few IndexSizeError: DOM Exceptions.  The actual device log shows many memory warnings:

```
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone MobileSafari[5559] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone discoveryd[1733] <Notice>: Basic DeviceInformation Memory Pressure Warning sent: pressure
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone HealthPrivacyService[533] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone MobilePhone[3702] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone MobileSMS[2551] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone MobileMail[1821] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Oct 31 13:19:49 iPhone backboardd[56] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long

...

Oct 31 13:19:52 iPhone backboardd[56] <Error>: CoreAnimation: insecure context 75d1e49e - pid 5559 [/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari].
    Cannot host 75d1e49e in context c37384c0 - pid 43 [/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard].
Oct 31 13:19:52 iPhone backboardd[56] <Error>: CoreAnimation: insecure context c1a3a9b7 - pid 5559 [/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari].
    Cannot host c1a3a9b7 in context c37384c0 - pid 43 [/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard].
Oct 31 13:19:52 iPhone backboardd[56] <Error>: CoreAnimation: insecure context 428372ba - pid 5559 [/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari].
    Cannot host 428372ba in context c37384c0 - pid 43 [/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard].
Oct 31 13:19:52 iPhone backboardd[56] <Error>: CoreAnimation: insecure context f5320d7f - pid 5559 [/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari].
    Cannot host f5320d7f in context c37384c0 - pid 43 [/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard].
```

It seems like you're doing a little too much for the device to handle.